# Get SUM form last 2 rows input with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have table like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFadB.png)

i want get sum from field 'total' from last 2 rows input,

this my code :

```
$data = DB::table('packagings')->where('plant',$pt->plant)->orderBy('id','desc')->limit(2)->sum('total');
```

but my code get all sum from field 'total'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql will sum `total` from table `packagings` firstly that will become one record, and then take 2 records from one record. So it always return all sum from field `total`.

#### Collection way:

```php
$data = DB::table('packagings')->where('plant',$pt->plant)->latest()->take(2)->get()->sum('total');
```

#### Query Builder way:

```php
$sub = DB::table('packagings')->where('plant',$pt->plant)->latest()->take(2);
$data = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) AS sub"))->mergeBindings($sub)->sum('total');
```

Comment: hi Koga, Thank you for your help.